# map key value pairs to specific columns in Google Sheets API v4 (PHP)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api-php-client

In version 3 of Google API , one could map values to specific columns using the header row and writing the entry like so..

```
<entry>
<gsx:$key><![CDATA[$value]]></gsx:$key>
</entry>
```

How can one do this using version 4 of the API?

Thanks.